# Keep EC2 Windows server alive after disconnection

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, google-chrome-extension, virtual-machine

I have Windows server in virtual machine (Amazon EC2).

I have Java Script that run on Chrome extension.

When I disconnect my virtual machine, my JavaScript stop running.

Is there any way to keep the Windows alive while I disconnected to it?

Comment: What do you mean by "disconnect"? How are you connecting to the EC2 instance and how are you "disconnecting"? Also, are you saying that you have logged into the EC2 instance, started a Chrome browser and started an extension, and you wish to keep the extension running?

Comment: I connect to my VM by Remote Desktop and by mRemote. "Disconnect" = Close Remote Desktop or click on "disconnect" on my machine in mRemote.
I wish to keep my extention running as long as the machine alive. Do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how come chrome knows that the user is disconnected, but if thats the cause.

You can rdp from the remote session to localhost (to another user of course), then open chrome in that inner session, keep the inner session connected when you disconnect from the external session.

Comment: Thanks. But I think it AWS issue. AWS from any reason take my E2C to sleep when I disconnect it.  Does anybody  has an idia how can I keep my machine alive

Comment: This would be totally unrelated to AWS. The instance is running normal the normal Windows operating system.

Comment: There's a way to keep it alive, i forgot how i did it in the past, I just setup another one, will reply here if i find the solution to it.

Comment: is it the regular windows power settings n control panel?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if someone still wants to know but like RedSkull, here I am to guide the path to a roundabout solution. After spending the entire day on the problem, scraping through the different solutions and adding bit-by-bit. Here's the detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72798188/12743648

---

it's original problem : [Can the GUI of an RDP session remain active after disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887729/can-the-gui-of-an-rdp-session-remain-active-after-disconnect/72798188#72798188)