# Does KARATE ROBOT require an active remote desktop connection for Windows automation?

Tags: windows, karate

As KARATE-ROBOT runs on top of UIAUTOMATION (Windows) and AWT ROBOT, for Windows element identification and automation, is  an active remote desktop connection required for running tests successfully on a server/VM ?

Reference Thread from another Windows automation library : https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-run-flaui-tests-on-a-build-serveragent

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track. Here are the best resources I've found so far on this aspect:

https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/keeping-computer-unlocked.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51336709/143475

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24529629/143475

It can take some work and fiddling to get it to work. One extra tip is the [`PsExec.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) utility can be used to create a session using the right user, GUI session etc.

Comment: Sure . Weve configured Winappdriver to run on our servers in a similar fashion : https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/pull/1368