# Does Karate.robot supports CI /CD with Bamboo and need visible desktop like Sikuli to run the script?

Tags: karate

I used image locators to locate some desktop elements the following question came to my mind that regarding Karate. Robot.

Can desktop script run on VM using CI/CD pipeline? does it need a physical desktop?

Previously I worked on Sikuli that needed a physical desktop if I minimize then the script does not work, is it the same case with Karate. Robot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can install Karate on the VM it should be fine. Yes, having to do an RDP session can get complicated. You will need to spend some time to figure this out, but we know teams that have done this. It is also an opportunity for you to contribute some reference material and hopefully code to the community. For example getting different resolutions to work can be a challenge.

If you use the `Element.invoke()` method (not documented) on elements that support that automation method (e.g. buttons) you don't need the UI to be visible.

All available information can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65187737/143475

If you have more questions, the best option is to figure this out on your own - and report your findings back here for the benefit of others.