# Does Chrome.robot support parallel run

Tags: karate

I was working on the Cucumber report then found the parallel option, as of now I am running only #1 thread and using parallel =false in the feature file. As per my understanding, we cant use parallelism with the karate.robot as it needs one activated window with a title. Please correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main challenge is that most of the UI interactions assume that the "active" window is "on top", visible and has focus. If you can figure out a way to use `Element.invoke()` for everything, maybe - but you will need to experiment.

Personally I feel that the better strategy is to split your test suite across multiple cloud nodes, and maybe virtual-machines or EC2 instances will work, provided you get the [RDP stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68988110/143475) sorted out.

Note that Karate has a way to run distributed tests: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Distributed-Testing - it may need some research though.