# Can I use Karate Test Case to connect to a windows machine

Tags: cucumber, karate, web-api-testing

I have one windows machine from where I am running karate test cases .I have another windows machine which I can access using RDP. Is there a way, I can create a karate test case to connect to other window machine as I need to check existence of some files.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as not officially supported, but you may need to do some research into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65187737/143475

But keep in mind that Karate can do anything if an API exists. You can be creative and start a mock-server on the other windows machine. Then anything is possible.