# Is it possible to execute karate robot scripts on virtual desktops (VDI)?

Tags: robotframework, ui-automation, karate

Here I have a scenario where I need to upload a file by clicking on the upload button on the UI application. I have tried using the driver.inputFile but, it is not working for this kind of button. So, I have used the karate robot functionalities as mentioned in [How can I upload a PDF file using Karate UI Automation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61391951/how-can-i-upload-a-pdf-file-using-karate-ui-automation) and, it has worked fine in my Local machine. But when I tried to implement the same functionality on the VDI robot framework has failed abruptly. I know it can be done by "multipart file" Since it is UI automation, I need to be accurate on that upload functionality using the user interface.

Any help would be appreciated and that will save my day.

Thank you.

Comment: yes this will be hard. the only thing I can do is point you to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65187737/143475

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Sorry, @PeterThomas, I think I didn’t express my problem correctly. I am not disconnecting from VDI while running the tests. The robot framework is not getting initialized in VDI. The tests were starting to fail once the execution reached the following step  
* robot {app: ‘^Chrome’, highlight: true}        Is there a way to use this robot FW along with karate UI on VDI’s

Comment: honest answer: I don't know. this is an area that needs research. if you don't have the bandwidth to do that and contribute fixes (if needed) to an open-source project, you may need to look for other options. this is just my opinion, and if you are lucky, someone else may come along and help you