# GUI of an RDP session remain active after disconnect with 4K screen resolution

Tags: windows, rdp

I use [this guid][1] to use RDP with GUI after disconnect. I use

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (tscon.exe %%s /dest:console)
```

in .bat file.
When I try to connect to server with UltraViewer, I see desktop with 1024x768 screen resolution. But I need use 4K screen resolution. This 4K screen resolution I use in RDP. Why? Can I get 4K screen resolution? I need it in my program. I use windows 10 pro at server.
[1]: [Can the GUI of an RDP session remain active after disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887729/can-the-gui-of-an-rdp-session-remain-active-after-disconnect/51336709#51336709)