How to keep Windows Server session active to run Puppeteer in full screen?
I have the following Node.js aplication running with Express on a Windows Server.
My goal is to visit a website in full screen / windowed mode, using the original browser from the computer, because in headless mode the website is blocking my request.
This is working as long as I stay connected to the Windows Server RDS and keep it active.
When I disconnect from RDS it is like Puppeteer or Chrome is freezing and not answering anymore.
I have tried stuff like this but doesn't seem to work: https://www.anyviewer.com/how-to/keep-rdp-session-alive-0007.html
Some of the errors I get:
Scraping URL: https://www.example.com/path/to/page/
Launch browser..
Get page..
Navigate..
An error occurred: ProtocolError: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Execution context was destroyed.
    at <instance_members_initializer> (C:\Projects\nexo-crawler-puppeteer\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\CallbackRegistry.js:93:14)
    at new Callback (C:\Projects\nexo-crawler-puppeteer\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\CallbackRegistry.js:97:16)
    at CallbackRegistry.create (C:\Projects\nexo-crawler-puppeteer\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\CallbackRegistry.js:22:26)
    at Connection._rawSend (C:\Projects\nexo-crawler-puppeteer\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\Connection.js:80:26)
    at CdpCDPSession.send (C:\Projects\nexo-crawler-puppeteer\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\CDPSession.js:66:33)
    at #evaluate (C:\Projects\nexo-crawler-puppeteer\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\ExecutionContext.js:202:50)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\Projects\nexo-crawler-puppeteer\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\ExecutionContext.js:117:16)
    at async IsolatedWorld.evaluate (C:\Projects\nexo-crawler-puppeteer\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\IsolatedWorld.js:124:16)
    at async CdpJSHandle.evaluate (C:\Projects\nexo-crawler-puppeteer\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\api\JSHandle.js:142:20)

So I don't know if the problem is with Puppeteer or with keeping Windows session active, but I guess it has to do more with the second, as long as it works while the RDS is connected but fails when it is not.
So how can I keep Puppeteer / Chrome alive after disconnecting from the server?
This is the original script:
const express = require('express');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const app = express();

let browser;
let page;

app.get('/scrape', async (req, res) => {

  let result = {};

  const { url } = req.query;
  
  if (!url) {
    return res.status(400).send('Please provide a URL to scrape');
  }

  console.log(`Scraping URL: ${url}`);

  // get browser
  console.log(`Launch browser..`);
  try {
    if (!browser) {
      browser = await puppeteer.connect({
        //browserWSEndpoint: wsChromeEndpointurl,
        browserURL: 'http://localhost:9222',
        defaultViewport: null,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
    result.error=`Could not connect to browser: ${error}`;
    return res.send(result);
  }
  
  // get page
  console.log(`Get page..`);
  try {
    if (!page) {
      page = await browser.newPage();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);

    result.error=`Could not connect to page: ${error}`;
    return res.send(result);
  }
  
  // navigate to URL
  console.log(`Navigate..`);
  try {
    //const response=await page.goto(url);
    const response=await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
    const statusCode=response.status();

    result.statusCode=statusCode;
    console.log('statusCode:', statusCode);

    if (statusCode != 200) {
      result.error="Invalid status code";
      return res.send(result);
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
    
    result.error=`Could not navigate to URL: ${error}`;
    return res.send(result);
  }

  // get the page title
  console.log(`Get title..`);
  try {
    const title = await page.title();
    result.title=title;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);

    result.error=`Could not get page title: ${error}`;
    return res.send(result);
  }

  // get the side content: #side-content
  console.log(`Check if user did not provide phone..`);
  try {
    const sideContentSelector='#side-content';
    await page.waitForSelector(sideContentSelector);

    const sideContentText = await page.evaluate(sideContentSelector => {
      const sideContentEl = document.querySelector(sideContentSelector);
      return sideContentEl.textContent.trim();
    }, sideContentSelector);

    if (sideContentText.search('no ha facilitado teléfono') !== -1) {

      result.no_phone_provided="yes";
      result.error=`User did not provide any phone.`;
      return res.send(result);

    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);

    result.error=`Could not find side-content block: ${error}`;
    return res.send(result);
  }

  // find and click view phones link
  console.log(`Click link..`);
  try {
    const phoneLink = await page.waitForSelector('#contact-phones-container > a');
    await phoneLink.click();
    await sleep(3000);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);

    result.error=`Could not find phone link button: ${error}`;
    return res.send(result);
  }

  // now get the phones
  console.log(`Get phones..`);
  try {
    
    // Wait for the results page to load and display the results.
    const resultsSelector = '#contact-phones-container a._mobilePhone';
    await page.waitForSelector(resultsSelector);

    // Extract the results from the page.
    const phones = await page.evaluate(resultsSelector => {
      const anchors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(resultsSelector));
      return anchors.map(anchor => {
        const phone = anchor.textContent.trim();
        return phone;
      });
    }, resultsSelector);

    result.phones=phones;

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);

    result.error=`Could not find any phones after clicking: ${error}`;
    return res.send(result);
  }

  console.log(result);

  res.send(result);

});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}


There's a lot of code here. What are you trying to achieve exactly, at a high level? Keeping a browser alive is just a matter of moving it out of the route, something like this (bottom code snippet). I guess you can use ifs but that seems a bit iffy design to me. Keeping the page alive too is probably not the best idea, because if multiple clients connect they're fighting each other over a shared page. I'd just reuse a browser, but it depends on your use case.

Hi @ggorlen the code I think is almost irrelevant, what I'm trying to accomplish is to execute Puppeteer remotely through Express but since I want to rely on using Chrome in full screen, apparently the server kills the GUI after I disconnect. I think I might have got it solved with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887729/can-the-gui-of-an-rdp-session-remain-active-after-disconnect

I see. Did you try adding a human user agent or using puppeteer stealth plugin to avoid detection? This might be easier and faster even if you do find a workaround for the GUI. Execution context was destroyed typically happens due to a race condition, often forgetting to await a promise, or (if I recall correctly) using element handles that are stale after a navigation.

@ggorlen no I haven't yet, I just saw that connecting to the original Chrome instance and using GUI mode does the trick with the website and doesn't get blocked.

@ggorlen and yes my use case is very special and specific, basically I'm trying to reproduce real user behavior cause as soon as I launch multiple instances, the site will ban me, that's why I keep the window open, and it will only process one request at the time, per minute.
